# Python arcpy.mapping and refreshing the document

Tags: python, arcpy

Is there any way to refresh an ArcMap (.mxd) document with newly added layers in python without saving the document?

I have used python to complete automate a series of tasks and the last step is to dump the outputs into an arcmap document and pop the document so that the user of the script can take a look at the output data and decide if/where they would like to save the .mxd.

I have created a Default.mxd document which I reference in the script but I would like to keep it 'read-only' so that the user is forced to save their own document manually. However using the arcpy.mapping module I cannot "see" the data in the mxd unless I save it. Is there any way around this?

Below is an example of the script for what I am trying to accomplish.

```
# Import arcpy module
import os
import arcpy

FGDB = "C:\...\SomeFGDB.gdb"
arcpy.env.workspace = FGDB

RASTER1 = FGDB+"\\RASTER1"
RASTER2 = FGDB+"\\RASTER2"

DefaultMXD = r"C:\...\Default.mxd"
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(DefaultMXD)
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "*")[0]


RASTER1_LYR = arcpy.mapping.Layer(RASTER1)
RASTER2_LYR = arcpy.mapping.Layer(RASTER2)

mxd.activeView = df.name

arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, RASTER2_LYR,"TOP")
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, RASTER1_LYR,"TOP")


extent = RASTER1.getExtent()
df.extent = extent

mxd.activeView = df.name
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()

##########################################
#I would rather not save the default MXD
#mxd.save()
##########################################

del mxd, df

os.startfile(DefaultMXD)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to work without saving the changes somehow.  Think about it.  What your are doing with the script is changing an in-memory copy of the mxd.  There's no way of opening another instance of this copy without writing it out.  I would first make a copy of the default with something like this:

```
DefaultMXD = r"C:\...\Default.mxd"
newmxd = r'c:\temp\temp.mxd'
shutil.copy2(DefaultMXD, newmxd)
```

Then make the changes to the newmxd, save, and use os.startfile or subprocess.Popen to open it up. This keeps your Default.mxd unchanged, which is what I think you wanted.

good luck,  Mike